# Firebase not creating new specified endpoint

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am having difficulty creating and writing to a new endpoint in my Firebase database. What I'm trying to do is create a new child node titled `savedUser` and push to that newly created endpoint the current contents of my existing `user` node.

Here is the code I am using:

```
// this is the initial search that sets the data in the user
// endpoint
$("#searchButton").on("click", function(){
​
    firebase.database().ref().once("child_added", function(snapshot){
    // little lesson in closure
    // dry coding
    function ez(path){
      return snapshot.child(path).val();
    }
​
    var dataObject = { 
      gamertag: ez("gamertag"),
      totalKills: ez("totalKills"),
      totalDeaths: ez("totalDeaths"),
      totalGames: ez("totalGames")
    };
    //handlebars, getting template
    var sourceTemplate = $("#list-template").html();
​
    var template =  Handlebars.compile(sourceTemplate);
    //handlebars, sending object to DOM
    var templateHTML = template(dataObject);
​
    var $templateHTML = $(templateHTML);
​
    $("#profileSearch").append($templateHTML);
    
​
  });
  
});
​
var $confirmButton = $("#confirmButton");
​
// This is supposed to fire when the "save" button is clicked
$(document).on("click", "#confirm", function(event){
  event.preventDefault()
  // referencing database again to iterate and capture value
  firebase.database().ref().once("value", function(snapshot){
    function ez(path){
      return snapshot.child(path).val();
    }
    // same procedure so far
    var savedUserData = {
      gamertag: ez("gamertag"),
      totalKills: ez("totalKills"),
      totalDeaths: ez("totalDeaths"),
      totalGames: ez("totalGames")
    }
    
    function saveUser(newChildPath, data){
      firebase.database().ref(newChildPath).set(data)
    }
    // call the function saves at the endpoint "savedUser" 
    saveUser("savedUser/", savedUserData);
​
​
  });
});
```

The above code writes nothing to my database but based on the guides I have been looking at I should be doing this successfully. However this writes to my database:

```
function saveUser(childPath, data){
      firebase.database().ref(childPath).set(data)
    }
    saveUser("savedUser/", {new: "path"});


  });
});
```

On my database console I can find "/savedUser/new" and it updates no problem. But when I am trying to capture the data from the database and format it like the first example it doesn't work and nothing is written. In fact, the `savedUser` endpoint is erased. There must be a subtlety I'm missing. I'm not well-versed in Firebase.

Comment: Perhaps Firebase doesn't like this formatting `gamertag: ez("gamertag"),` for object properties? Also, try to include only the relevant code, i.e. why telling us about Handlebars?

Comment: What are the values in `savedUserData`? Do they all happen to be null? Is this really the minimum code needed to reproduce the problem? Seems like the problem set could be simplified quite a bit. Also, turn on debugging:  `firebase.database.enableLogging(true);`

Comment: @Ursus @Kato I was able to get it working by changing the paths in `savedUserData` to something like `"user/gamertag"`, for example and then everything was being sent off as it should have been. Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this code working by making the following changes to the code like so:

```
var savedUserData = {
  gamertag: ez("user/gamertag"),
  totalKills: ez("user/totalKills"),
  totalDeaths: ez("user/totalDeaths"),
  totalGames: ez("user/totalGames")
}
```

Above, I am referencing the path I want to take the data from. I need to do this because I am creating a new child `savedUser` and adding it to the root directory. That means when I am calling simply `ez("gamertag")` that code is looking for something in the root named `gamertag` but is really stored in `user/gamertag` a distinction that must be made with the addition of a `savedUser` node. Therefore I need to be more specific in the code where in my database I am searching with the addition of a new file in the directory and type out the paths more completely.